# Primary / Default ABMultiValue property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook, abmultivalue

I need a user to enter their name, phone number, and email address.  To help them out, if they enter any one of the three, I want to look up that value in their Address book and populate the remaining fields.  For example, if they enter their name, I'll look them up, and populate the email and phone number fields.

Email and phone numbers are ABMultivalue properties, however, and most people have more than one email and phone.  Does the iPhone address book have the concept of a primary or default value for those properties that are ABMultiValue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no primary/default value. I would simply assume that the first value is the primary/default value. It's true for most of my contacts. Otherwise if there are multiple values you could let the user choose the one they want, but you need to make a good UI to support it, so the first alternative is much simpler.